# Copy any command with variables, strings, literals and double/single quotes exactly to clipboard before executing it

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, scripts, clipboard

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr 32bit in my desktop.

Now I want a simplified command syntax to "Copy any command with variables, strings, literals and double/single quotes exactly to clipboard before executing it" in terminal, so I am aware of every command it is running if I am running `sh` script or a group of commands manually.

How can I do that ?

I tried below syntax but this removes double quotes/single quotes around the strings and literals, also it just prints the command into terminal but doesn't copy it to clipboard.

```
set -x
```

Or

```
bash -x script.sh
```

Comment: If you want an exact log of your terminal session, you can use the `script` command: [man script](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html)

Comment: Yes fine, but any command that will print(most probably write to clipboard) the command before or after executing it ?

Comment: Wouldn't Bash's `HISTORY` feature do the trick?